# redirect subdomain request to main domain using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

here is what I do and works good:

```
#redirect subdomains to controller
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]*)$ blog.php?blog_uid=%1 [L,QSA]
```

now I want to redirect

```
 http://example.domain.com/post-123.html
```

to

```
blog.php?blog_id=example&post_id=123
```

but this not works:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]*)/post-([0-9]+)\.html$ blog.php?blog_uid=%1&post_id=%2 [L,QSA]
```

how do it? actually how redirect such subdomain request to a rewrite condition (it is not a real page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this rule instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^post-([0-9]+)\.html$ /blog.php?blog_id=%1&post_id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^post-([^/]*)\.html$ /blog.php?blog_id=example&post_id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: "example" is not static it is subdomain name.

Comment: `blog_id="what-ever"` will be your sub domain. Is it right. @m3hdi